# ¿Cómo desplazar datos de un array en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Quizás sea algo sencillo pero no pude solucionarlo. Tengo un array que contiene los días de la semana en fomato númerico `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]`  y lo que quiero hacer es desplazar todos los datos 4 lugares atrás para que el primer día sea miercoles `3` y sea ahora: `[3,4,5,6,0,1,2]`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
     hor[i] = hor[i - 4];
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se lo recorre con `map`, se le suma *3* a cada elemento y se hace el resto de dividir por *7*.

```js
console.log( [0,1,2,3,4,5,6].map(x=>(x+3)%7) )
```

Comment: A quien corresponda: [Referencia de `Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @Rodrigo Es buena info, me había olvidado eso, entonces el array creado es una copia... Deberían cambiar la implementación del motor para que ya no lo sea... Es decir, en C los arrays pueden pasar como referencia y cambiar los valores de los caracteres del string, es solo una limitación que tiene JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías realizarlo de diferentes maneras aunque creo que la forma más sencilla es:  agregar al final el elemento en la posición 0, `array.push(array[0])`, para después eliminar el elemento en la primera posición `array.shift()`; Ejemplo de la implementación en formato de función:

```js
    let a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
    
    function shiftLeft( q ) {
        for (let i = 0; i < q; i++) {
            a.push(a[0]);
            a.shift();
        }
    }
    
    
    shiftLeft(3);
    console.log(a);
```